# Azure IoT: Cannot connect ESP8266 device to IoT Edge (Certificate error)

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I am able to **successfully connect with a python example** to my created IoT Edge. However, the same configuration does not work for my actual downstream device (ESP8266).

#### Downstream device (ESP8266) Configuration

I am using the following example for the ESP8266: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino/tree/master/examples/esp8266/iothub_ll_telemetry_sample

Added the certificate and connection string in the code:

```
// DEVICE_CONNECTION_STRING
HostName=iot-edge.leister;DeviceId=wemosd1mini;SharedAccessKey=XXXXXXXXX=

// CERTIFICATE
// same certificate as in python example (content of file azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem)
static const char edgeCert [] =
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n"
...
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r\n";
IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SetOption(device_ll_handle, OPTION_TRUSTED_CERT, edgeCert);
```

#### Edge Device Configuration

I configured a raspberry pi according to the documentation on (with demo certificates as mentioned in the article) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-create-transparent-gateway?view=iotedge-2018-06

I can successfully verify the certificate with the command `openssl s_client -connect iot-edge.leister:8883 -CAfile "C:\Users\micha\Desktop\azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem" -showcerts`

Results in: **Verify return code: 0 (ok)**

#### ESP8266 Logs

```
Creating IoTHub Device handle...
Sending message 1 to IoTHub...
dowork TLSIO_STATE_OPENING_WAITING_SOCKET
dowork TLSIO_STATE_OPENING_WAITING_SSL
Error opening socket 0
Calling error callback
The device client has been disconnected
Error: failure opening connection to endpoint
```

I am not able to connect with the **same configuration** to my IoT Edge with the ESP8266 as downstream device.

More details can be found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/1902

Comment: Have you added your downstream device as a child of the edge device? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/offline-capabilities?view=iotedge-2018-06#assign-child-devices

Comment: Yeah, I ve done that. Think the issue is the TLS check. Probably need to setup a local dns server to make a hostname available and try again if that works.

Comment: Yes, or set the hostname in the config.yaml of the edge device to 192.168.4.1 and restart iotedged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's working.
Switched the hardware from ESP8266 to ESP32 and running (same code) without any issues.

Comment: Note: No idea what the actual issue with the ESP8266 was.